# Парсинг с помощью Tor

Tags: c#, proxy

Нигде не нашел норм инфы, спрошу тут.
Как использовать тор для парсинга? Говорят его можно как прокси поставить? Вот что я намутил с кодом, вродьбы работает, прокси видит. Но я не знаю использую я тор при этом? И как определить? (+ я скачал privoxy)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sites);
                    req.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");

                    req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    req.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(sites);



                    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Какую нибудь страницу типа http://yandex.ru/internet/ скачайте через него и посмотрите какой ip дало. несколько раз с интервалом в полчаса попробуете - если ip разные значит тор. кроме того практически по любому ip можно узнать что он точка выхода тор-сети (по этому принципу кстати некоторые сайты уже защищаются что бы к ним через тор не ходили)

Comment: @Mike к сожалению спарсило мой настоящий ip. Может что-то в коде не так?

Comment: C# я не знаю. так что надо подождать кого то знающего.

Comment: Вы используете WebProxy и, следовательно, используете в качестве прокси не TOR. TOR дает только socks-прокси, а не HTTP, который у вас. Соответственно, нужно либо использовать socks, либо настраивать privoxy.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов может заинтересует http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593435/httpwebresponse-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8 ?? Никак не могу исправить